# How to use bold custom font in jspdf

Tags: jspdf

I'm trying to use a custom font with [jspdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) but i can't get to show the font as bold, I followed the steps specified [here](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF#use-of-utf-8--ttf).

here is the code:

```
require ("./js/Roboto-Regular-normal.js");
require ("./js/Roboto-Regular-bold.js");
let doc = new jsPDF();
   
doc.setFont('Roboto-Regular');
doc.setFontSize(8);
doc.text("hello world", 50 , 50);
doc.setFontType('bold');
doc.text("Hello Bold", 50, 55);

let blob = doc.output();
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('a5.pdf', blob, 'utf8', function(err){
    //Do something
});
```

Roboto-Regular-normal.js

```
(function (jsPDFAPI) {
    var font = base64_font; //I didn't include this string because is too large, let me know if I should include it anyways
    
    var callAddFont = function () {
        this.addFileToVFS("Roboto-Regular-normal.ttf", font);
        this.addFont("Roboto-Regular-normal.ttf", "Roboto-Regular", "normal");
    };
    jsPDFAPI.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
})(jsPDF.API);
```

Roboto-Regular-bold.js:

```
(function (jsPDFAPI) {
        var font = base64_font; //I didn't include this string because is too large, let me know if I should include it anyways
        
        var callAddFont = function () {
            this.addFileToVFS("Roboto-Regular-bold.ttf", font);
            this.addFont("Roboto-Regular-bold.ttf", "Roboto-Regular", "bold");
        };
        jsPDFAPI.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
})(jsPDF.API)
```

Nothing in the pdf appears as bold.

I'm using it in electron, I don't know if that changes anything.

Answer (score 7):

You can edit your JS file like this,

```
doc.text("This is example paragraph", 11,13,).setFontSize(8).setFont(undefined, 'bold');

doc.text("This is example paragraph", 11,13,).setFontSize(8).setFont(undefined, 'normal');
```

Output here,
[image: Result output]

Answer (score 6):

You could use:
`doc.setFont(undefined, 'bold').text("Your paragraph").setFont(undefined, 'normal')`
to set only one line in bold style

Comment: Hello @luís-guilherme-f-de-sena, welocme to stackoverflow. Please be more elaborate in your answers . Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer on how to write a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
##**React example jsPdf html**

const doc = new jsPDF()
doc.addFileToVFS('PTSans-Regular-normal.ttf', font)
doc.addFont('PTSans-Regular-normal.ttf', 'PTSans', 'normal')
doc.addFileToVFS('PT Sans Bold-bold.ttf', fontBold);
doc.addFont('PT Sans Bold-bold.ttf', 'PTSans', 'bold');
doc.setFont('PTSans')

doc.html(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<div style={{ fontFamily: 'PTSans' 
}}>{element}</div>), {
  callback: function (doc) {
    doc.save('filename'+ '.pdf')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way! There is a 'hard' way. You have to use a separate bold variant font file. If you can get hold of it good - else you will have to generate it yourself, keeping in mind that the font license allows you to do so.

The software I used was: [fontforge](https://fontforge.org). In there:

1. Select all symbols using: ctrl+A
2. Change weight from: `Element`>`Style`>`Change weight`
3. `Embolden by`: 12 ems, `LCG` (for latin, crylic & greek), `Counters`: squish, `Cleanup self intersect`
4. `Correct direction`: right click > `correct direction`
5. Generate font

Now as with the earlier font file you can add this bold version under the 'bold' label with 'addFont'

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/199#issuecomment-73009553

doc.setFontType("bold");
doc.text(20, 20, "This is a bold paragraph");

doc.setFontType("normal")
doc.text(40, 40, "This is a normal font paragraph");

Comment: This works for "jspdf": "^1.4.1", but not "jspdf": "^2.4.0",